# Some executables refuse to download on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, download

I'm setting up a new Windows 8.1 computer. It refuses to download certain files -- they'll download the first few hundred KB, but then stall.  This happens on IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

Every non-executable file I've tried to download works fine. The executable downloads that don't work include AVG from their site and Avast from cnet. Executable downloads that do work include Start Menu 8 from cnet and the Spotify installer. (Yes, one download from a certain site works and another from the same site doesn't).

I've disabled [QoS packet scheduling](https://superuser.com/questions/311703/http-downloads-stall-hang-after-1-5mb/311708). I've disabled [TCP window scaling](https://superuser.com/a/95097/156829). I tried disabling Windows Firewall. I removed McAfee and any other crapware that came with the computer that seemed like it might cause a problem. I made sure the account has write access to the Downloads folder, and tried downloading to other folders. I made sure downloads are enabled in Internet Options. I restarted more than once. I made sure the date and time are synced. I'm completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's executable **only** that are affected, it seems like an antivirus (AV) is over-zealous. You might also try to download using Free Download Manager, http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/.
You might temporarily disable the AV, download, and then check the file manually with your AV and with Virus Total. *Don't forget to restart the AV!*

Comment: That was my first guess, but I don't have any antivirus installed at the moment (none of the antivirus installers will download >:|). I removed McAfee, and the only security-related thing remaining seems to be Windows Firewall, and disabling that temporarily doesn't let these downloads through.  
  
Amazingly, this same problem occurs with Free Download Manager, on the same files -- it makes it to a few hundred KB then stops completely.

Comment: Could it be an external firewall issue? Many businesses forbid downloading executables for security. Another possibility is that, since you're running sans AV, your machine is infected with malware, which is protecting itself by preventing download of an antivirus.